# In Python error on sys.stdin.fileno()

Tags: python

I get the error when I run `sys.stdin.fileno()`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    sys.stdin.fileno()
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to RPi.SE. This question is more like a python question rather than an RPi question.

Comment: It appears that `sys.stdin` is not a real `file` but rather a `file`-like object that doesn't have a `fileno`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're running in IDLE; IDLE maintains its own pseudo-terminal, and that pseudo-terminal is not actually based on "real" files (something for which a kernel file descriptor exists). As such, it has no `fileno` to get; use a plain shell, not an IDE shell if you want `fileno` to work.